# Please someone help me to make sure my prove that Sn bounded is correct

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Please someone help me to make sure my prove that $S_n$ bounded is correct.

I want to prove that $S_n=sum \sin(2n+1)x$ is bounded. I am sure about $$S_n=\frac{\cos(0)x-\cos(2n+2)x}{2\sin x}$$ $$|S_n|\le\frac{2}{2|\sin x|}$$ $$|S_n|\le\frac{2}{2|\sin x|}=\frac{1}{|\sin x|}.$$

But I am not sure about  $|\cos(0)x-\cos(2n+2)x|\le2.$

Comment: yes we do it like 2 sinx *sin(2n+1)x  Then we use this role {2 sin alpha sin bita=cos(alph+bita)- cos (alph+bta)}after we have Telescoping series then every thing cancel except cos(0)x - cos(2n+2)x. I am sure about every things except |cos(0)_cos(2n+2)| <2

Comment: Sorry, but why are you talking about series? One could easily interpret what you've written as referring to a sequence of functions (S_n). It may be a good idea to clarify your question.

Comment: yes it is sum of sin(2n+1)x from 0-->n

Answer (score -3):

For $\lvert \cos(0)x−\cos(2n+2)x\rvert\leq 2$.

The maximum value of a cosine is $1$, so the difference between two cosines cannot be greater than $2$

Comment: How should we read your expression? See this [homegrown MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quickstart on use mathematical symbols and equations.